# Cloning Android Devices

Tags: adb

I would like to know if it is possible to clone a physical Android device with all settings, apps and configuration to inject it on other Android devices such as an image of the device. And if it is possible, how can I do this ? My Android device is an Android 7.1 and I'm connecting it to an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
We are professional and don't want to reinstall each devices, so I ask for a simple way with ADB or other, to clone what is legal to clone, the setup. 
I have one device, with his app and settings, I need to clone it on 15 devices... 
Simple ADB backup won't do it, it just backup files pictures but no apps. 
Thx

Comment: cloning wifi/ bluetooth mac addresses may confuse dhcp router, cloning imei may illegal in your country. please be more specific about what is your intent

Comment: I would like to clone an android device, apps and settings. 
We are professional and don't want to reinstall each devices, so I ask for a simple way with ADB or other, to clone what is legal to clone, the setup. 
I have one device, with his app and settings, I need to clone it on 15 devices... What can I do. 
Simple ADB backup won't do it, it just backup files pictures but no apps. Thx

Comment: I suspected that. not cloning but batch setup of individual devices each with it's own phone number google/whatsapp/email account. just app settings should be same. adb backup can include apk, but not phone settings. is a solution for rooted devices also accepted?

Comment: What you describe is not cloning of a device but cloning of user data. Anyway totally cloning the data is a bad idea as this would also include the ANDROID_ID - an ID with should be unique. Check this url for a typical enrollment via e.g. NFC or QR-code: https://developers.google.com/android/management/provision-device

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=balti.migrate

Comment: Do you think it is possible to clone a setup as :
- Copy all applications
- Settings and user data (simply basic settings on application like the background image or restarting an app at the startup of the device)

Comment: you need custom recovery then you can create a flashable zip with all necessary settings. the above app is a helper for creating such a zip. It includes also phone settings not just app settings. but i am not aware about a fully hands free setup solution for adb. the closed non-root solution i can imagine is android-backup-toolkit